# How can I protect a class member variable pointer?

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to protect a class from receiving a NULL pointer at compiler time.

```
class B
{
   // gives some API

}


class A
{


    private:
        B* ptrB_;
    
    public:
        A(B* ptrB) 
        {
            // How can I prevent the class to be created with a null pointer?
            ptrB_ = ptrB;
        }

        // multiple member function using: ptrB_ 
        void A::Func1(void)
        {
            if(!ptrB_ )
                rerturn; // I don't want to add it in every function.

            ...

            return;
        }

}


int main()
{
   B tempB = NULL;
   A tempA(&tempB);
}
```

How can I force user to always pass a pointer (not NULL) to A constructor?

Was looking at `constexpr` , but this forces to use `static` , and that's something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Just test it once in the constructor, and throw an exception if a `NULL` pointer was passed. Yet better use smart pointers instead.

Comment: Use a reference, it can't be null

Comment: I'd also mention `gsl::not_null<>`

Comment: fwiw, passing and storing a reference changes semantics of the class, but chances are high that you didnt want a pointer in the first place. Who ows the `B` (when it is not a `nullptr`) ?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the risk of `NULL` pointers, don't pass a pointer at all, instead use references (there are no 'null' references).

e.g.

```
A(B* ptrB) { ptrB_ =  ptrB; } //instead of passing the address of an object
A(B& ptrB) { ptrB_ = &ptrB; } //take and store the address of the reference
```